# Change of basis in R2

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Question from linear algebra textbook:

Bases B = {(1, 1), (1, -1)} = {u1, u2} and B` = {(2, 0), (3, 1)} = {u`1, u`2} are given.

a) Find the change of basis from the standard basis to each of these.

This part seems straightforward.  With {e1, e2} forming the R2 identity matrix, u1 = e1 + e2 and u2 = e1 - e2.  Similarly, u`1 = 2e1 and u`2 = 3e1 + e2.

b) Use a) to find the change of basis from B to B` with T = R2 identity matrix I

For this, I first found the inverse of B` to be {(1/2, -3/2), (0, 1)}.  So, the change-of-basis M = B`^-1 * I * B:

{(1/2, -3/2), (0, 1)} * {(1, 0), (0, 1)} * {(1, 1), (1, -1)} = {(1/2, -1/2), (1/2, -5/2)}

I am fairly confident in the above. But, I'm struggling with part c, which is:

c) Given that w = 3u1 + 4u2, use b) to express w as a linear combination of u`1 and u`2.

Fairly unsure where to start here.  I think the result w is {(3, 3), (4, -4)}.  But, I'm not seeing a linear combination of the u`1 and u`2 vectors that results in w, nor do I see the connection with the result from b).

Comment: There is something wrong in all your derivation, I've added a full solution check a tell me for an doubt.

Comment: Some aspects of your Question need clarification.  You've written "vectors" in $\mathbb R^2$ as ordered pairs, which is okay, but it is unclear whether you intend these to be interpreted for the sake of change of basis as rows or as columns.  Columns are a conventional choice, so that the change of basis is done by multiplying on their left by a matrix, but in principle using rows we would do this task by multiplication on the right by a matrix (the transpose of the column multiplier).  To get started with proper math notation, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the link.  I was using tuple notation, but better formatting of the equations and matrices can only help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the matrix M which represent the change of basis from B to B' you can compute

$$(a,b)=M(3,4)$$

such that

$$au_1'+bu_2'=3u_1+4u_2$$

It seems there is something wrong in your calculation, indeed

For **point 1** we have

$$M_{SB}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \implies M_{BS}=M^{-1}_{SB}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac12 & \frac12 \\ \frac12 & -\frac12 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$M_{SB'}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \implies M_{B'S}=M^{-1}_{SB'}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac12 & -\frac32\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

For **point 2** we have

$$v_S=M_{SB}v_B \quad v_B'=M_{B'S}v_S \implies v_B'=M_{B'S}M_{SB}v_B $$

thus

$$M_{B'B}=M_{B'S}M_{SB}=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

For **point 3** we have

$$M_{B'B} \begin{pmatrix} 3\\4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3\\4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 5\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

and indeed

$$3u_1+4u_2=5u_1'-u_2'=\begin{pmatrix} 7\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yep, this all checks out.  It looks like there was an error in my calculation of $$M^{-1}_{SB'}, which threw off all the subsequent steps.  Thank you @gimusi!

Comment: You are welcome! Remember to accept the answer to set it as solved http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png